# What good websites which list the requirements of various plants?

Tags: optimal-conditions, resources, native-conditions

This may sound like a weird one, but I am working on a plant ecosystem simulator as part of my research and am looking for property data on various plant species. Ideally, this data would include, amongst other properties:

- Light requirements
- Soil moisture requirements
- Lifespan

Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Was this program ever completed and made available for download?

Comment: No, afraid not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I can find is [PlantFiles](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/), which is a huge database, and covers these criteria:

- Height
- Spacing
- Hardiness
- Sun Exposure
- Danger
- Bloom Color
- Bloom Time
- Foliage
- Other details
- Soil pH requirements
- Patent Information
- Propagation Methods
- Seed Collecting